# Transformer MMF distribution

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, magnetics

The below figure is referring to *The Analysis and Comparison of Leakage Inductance in Different Winding Arrangements for Planar Transformer*.

It is a common method to use MMF distribution to estimate the leakage inductance in the transformer, but do you guys know why we only care about the h direction MMF? Don't we care about bw direction?

Could you introduce some papers talking about this that I can read?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say "h" or "bw" directions?

Comment: "x" and "y" direction in this figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, both distribution (axial and radial) are important. Tipically, for core-type transformers with concentrical windings, the radial distribution dominates the reactance generation, but it can be the opposite for different windings configurations.

The Kulkarni's book ("Transformer Engineering - Design, Technology and Diagnostics") contains a good and well-explained method to compute the reactance in transformers based on the ampere-turns diagram.

Comment: The book explain about the  MMF distribution?

Comment: Yes, you will find good information in chapter 3 (Impedance Characteristics). You can have in mind that this MMF distribution is, in fact, the ampere-turn diagram for a transformer. And another important thing is that for a transformer, the ampere-turns always sums to zero. So, the diagram will go up and down. This ups and downs are due to the presence of some current carrying element (a coil).